# Using installed SD Card from B+ in new 3

Tags: sd-card, update

I'm having trouble finding this somewhere, I got a new Pi 3, can I just place my SD card currently running on my B+ in the 3 and boot like normal?

Or do I need any more configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My notes on the architecture of the different PIs is as follows:
[image]

The PI3 is a very different architecture for the Pi 1 Model B+.  I would recommend that you obtain a second micro SD card and install a fresh Raspbian upon it.

Comment: OK, thank you. A new SD card is not the problem, the current configuration is though. Lots of stuff installed.

Comment: **There is absolutely no need to do that.**   The B+ and the 3 use a different kernel.  The appropriate kernel is loaded from the first partition at boot time, as are the corresponding device tree overlays.  All recent versions of Raspbian have both of these present (it's the same kernel as used on the 2, although the device tree configuration is different).   While the system is running, the kernel loads driver modules as needed from directories in `/lib/modules`, hence there is a set for each one.  It is impossible for a kernel to load a module that was not built for it.

Comment: Since the kernel is the gatekeeper of all hardware, after this point it is completely fine to use the exact same userland software (you don't have any choice anyway). There is only *one* version of the software, and it doesn't matter whether you use it on a separate card or not.   This idea that there is some danger lurking here is just superstition.  The exception to this are pi-specific GPIO libs that access hardware through `/dev/mem`.  However, simply using a separate SD card does nothing to protect you from making a mistake with that.

Comment: @goldilocks I just tried booting a Pi 3 with the OSMC image I'd been using on a Pi 1 Model B. The green LED lit up one briefly, no other reaction. I ended up backing up the config and restoring it to a fresh install but I'd like to know if there's a way to add in the missing kernel and not have to reinstall everything from scratch.

Comment: @user149408 Just like S.O. this *isn't* a discussion forum -- if you have a question, ask a question ;)

Comment: @goldilocks you're right, here you go: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/58195/57126